Wordpress : Create a widget Elementor how to display in live preview
I have to create a widget Elementor and display a badge in dark theme and light theme when I select the option. I have 2 methods in another file to create these badges. This code displays both badges and several. I think I have to add JS content_template but I don't know how to do
$this->add_control(
    'size',
    [
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Size', 'textdomain' ),
        'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
        'default' => 'small',
        'options' => [
            'Small' => esc_html__( 'small', 'textdomain' ),
            'Medium' => esc_html__( 'medium', 'textdomain' ),
            'Large'  => esc_html__( 'large', 'textdomain' ),
        ],
        'selectors' => [
            '{{WRAPPER}} .your-class' => 'size: {{VALUE}};',
        ],
    ]
);
$this->add_control(
    'theme',
    [
        'label' => __( 'Badge Theme', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
        'options' => [
            'light' => __( 'Light', 'your-text-domain' ),
            'dark' => __( 'Dark', 'your-text-domain' ),
        ],
        'default' => 'light', // Set default theme
    ]
);

$this->end_controls_section();
}
public function render(){
    //include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/WoosterPartnerBadges.php';
    $woosterPartnerBadges = new WoosterPartnerBadges();
    // Get the selected theme
    $theme = $this->get_settings_for_display('Theme');
    if (get_option('partner_license') && get_option('partner_license') != '') {
        $certificate = '#528085301-122301';
    } else {
        $certificate = '#XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXX';
    }
    //var_dump($theme);
    //$certificate = '#528085301-122301';
        if ($theme == 'Dark') {
        //     // If the Dark theme is selected, display the dark badge
            echo $woosterPartnerBadges->woosterPartnerBadgeDark($certificate, 'https://wooster.fr/', 'https://wooster.fr/?partner-certificate=' . $certificate);
        } else {
        //     // Otherwise, display the light badge
            echo $woosterPartnerBadges->woosterPartnerBadgeLight($certificate, 'https://wooster.fr/', 'https://wooster.fr/?partner-certificate=' . $certificate);
        }
}

